# File.Readline is giving error in .net 3.5

Tags: c#

I have the following code where I am having error in File.ReadLines in .net framework 3.5.
 I am not able to use File.readAlllines as after giving this the error comes in File.WriteAlllines method
Please suggest

```
string Activestorelist = @"C:\Activestores_default.txt";
var file1 = File.ReadLines(Activestorelist);
var file2 = File.ReadAllLines(savePath);
var onlyInFileA = file1.Except(file2);   
File.WriteAllLines(savePath, onlyInFileA);
```

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: File.Readlines is not supported for .net framework 3.5. I am not able to use File.Readalllines here also as it will give me error in File.Writealllines method.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't use a higher version of `.NET Framework` then use `StreamReader` or write your own method.It's not so diffucult.For example:

```
public static class FileHelper
{
    public static string[] ReadAllLines(string path)
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                while(!reader.EndOfStream)
                    lines.Add(reader.ReadLine());
            }
            return lines.ToArray();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var file2 = FileHelper.ReadAllLines(savePath);
```

Comment: can you please tell me with the above example i have given ?